# "Никто" спереди и сзади оборота, - знаки?

Tags: пунктуация, выбор-слов

> Интересно, что несмотря на столь долгое забвение этого дворца и
>   множество равнодушных людей, здесь побывавших, оценивающих и
>   распродающих, никто – включая бригаду ремонтников и уборщиц, никто не
>   тронул интимную вещь последней хозяйки.

Знаки нетронутые.

А фотографию в рамке можно ль назвать *интимной* вещью?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Знаки препинания расставлены верно.

Это тема **повторяющихся слов**.

Между повторяющимися словами может ставится **запятая**, при этом второе слово может иметь свои распространители. В данном случае это оборот со значением включения, обособленный тире и относящийся к местоимению ***никто***.

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=105

2. Если после повторяющегося слова (или словосочетания с ним) при чтении не делается паузы, то никакими знаками препинания от последующих слов в предложении это слово не отделяется: Лес, сплошной лес окружал нас со всех сторон; Часто, очень часто можно наблюдать подобные явления;  Важно установить **предельные, повторяю — предельные сроки** строительства дороги; Он был **наивен, более того — чрезвычайно наивен** до этой истории;

**ИНТИМНЫЙ**,  [от франц. intime] 1. Касающийся **личной** жизни человека, его отношений с близкими людьми.  // Касающийся области **чувств, сокровенный, глубоко личный**.

Домашнее это словечко… **Интимные фотографии**…[С. Б. Рассадин. Книга прощаний. Воспоминания о друзьях и не только о них (2004-2008)]